# How can I make catch2 run tests that reside in a static library?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, catch-unit-test, catch2

My usual workflow with [catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) is to have a single console application that contains all the test cases and the tests 'runner'.

For example:

file1.cpp, file2.cpp contains tests:

```
#include <catch2/catch.hpp>

TEST_CASE("test", "[test]")
{
    CHECK(true);
}
```

A single file main.cpp would contain the runner code:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER
#include <catch2/catch.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return Catch::Session().run(argc, argv); // run tests
}
```

In order to reduce compilation time, I tried to move all files containing the tests (file1, file2 etc) to a separate static library project (Visual Studio).

But after doing this, catch fails to find any test cases:

```
catch main started..
Filters: [test]
===============================================================================
No tests ran
```

I tried putting the runner code inside a function that resides inside the static library, but that didn't help.

Questions:

- How exactly does catch finds its test cases?
- Why is this failing?
- How can I fix it?